# Player is not a valid member of DataModel "Game"

Tags: lua, roblox

```lua
local Player = game.Player:GetPlayerFromCharacter(Hit.Parent)"
```

It gives an error when I try stepping on a certain button to make a dropper appear, and just so you know, I'm trying to make a tycoon. (Keep in mind that this is NOT the full script I wrote.)

Comment: I guess Player is not a valid member of Game. Is it?

Answer (score 0):

It's `game.Players`, not `game.Player`.